# Probability combinations

Tags: probability

I am really confused on the outcomes of probability
For example
In a class of equal amounts of boys and girls, when two students are picked, there are apparently four possible combinations (boy & girl, boy & boy, girl & boy, girl & girl) even though boy & girl and girl & boy are the same

However in another example question
In a stall that sells apples, bananas and pears, when two fruits are picked there are apparently six possible combinations (apples & apples, apples & bananas, apples & pears, bananas & bananas, bananas & pears, pears & pears) which seems to be different from the boy-girl example because if the same way was used then it would be 9 combinations

So in the first example question why is boy & girl and girl & boy regarded as different combinations when in the second question, apples & bananas and bananas & apples are regarded as the same combination (and therefore are not noted down as a different combination)?
Please help this is extremely urgent

Comment: $[G, B$ and $[B, G]$ can be regarded as different combinations if the order of the sequence in the sample is important.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be confusing. However usually the word "combination" is used to refer to the fact that the order does not matter. While the word permutation or list is used when the order does matter.

For example: consider the following question: if we flip two coins: what is the probability that we don't get the same result twice. In other words this is equivalent to the statement: What is the probability we get heads in one flip and tails in the other?(without the order mattering).

To do this we can use the fact that the probability of the following four outcomes are equally likely(25%): HH,HT,TH,TT. (notice the order here does matter). to get our answer we see that the probability of getting either HT or TH is 50%. Which is one half.